# Addition of Fractions in a Loop

Tags: java, loops, logic

I was assigned an assignment where I have to create a program to add the following numbers and then tell the user the answer while using a loop statement.

(1/3 + 3/5 + 5/7 + 7/9 + 9/11 + 11/13 + ... 95 / 97 + 97/99)
The answer should be 45.12445 according to the professor but I am receiving the answer 40.92541 and I'm having trouble figuring out where the error in my logic is.

```
public class HW6
public static void main(String[]args)
    {
            //Declarations
            double num;
            double denom;
            double holder1;
            double sum;
            num=1;
            denom = 3;
            sum=0;


            // Perform loop
            for (num=1;num<=98;num=num+2) {
                    num = num+2;
                    denom = denom+2;
                    holder1 = num/denom;
                    sum= sum+holder1;
                    }

            // Print sum
            System.out.println("The sum is " +sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand the problem in your logic, take it one step at a time. Your initialization before the loop looks fine, so let's start at the beginning of the loop:

**Iteration 1**

```
for (num=1;num<=98;num=num+2) {
```

At this point, your variables contain the following:

num == 1, denom == 3, sum == 0, and holder == undefined (because you didn't initialize it)

After the following statement:

```
num = num+2;
```

`num` changes to 3, so we now have:

num == **3**, denom == 3, sum == 0, and holder == undefined.

After the next statement:

```
denom = denom+2;
```

`denom` changes from 3 to 5, so we have:

num == 3, denom == **5**, sum == 0, and holder == undefined.

Then, after

```
holder1 = num/denom;
```

we have the first calculated fraction, which (since num==3 and denom==5) is 3/5, or 0.6. You will probably notice that this is not what you intended, because according to your assignment the first fraction in the series is supposed to be 1/3. So the first problem with your logic is that you are adding 2 to both `num` and `denom` before you calculate the first fraction in the series.

Continuing to step through your code, after

```
sum= sum+holder1;
```

the variables contain

num == 3, denom == 5, sum == 0.6, and holder == 0.6.

**Iteration 2**

Now before looping back to execute the next iteration of the `for` loop, the `num` variable will be incremented by 2, as specified by the third expression in your `for` loop definition: `num=num+2`. So when the loop begins for the second iteration, the variables contain:

num == **5**, denom == 5, sum == 0.6, and holder == 0.6.

As before, the next two statements increment `num` and `denom`, respectively, by 2, so before the next fraction is computed, the variables contain:

num == **7**, denom == **7**, sum == 0.6, and holder == 0.6.

Variable `holder` is then computed as `num/denom` = 7/7 = 1.0 (which is certainly not a fraction that is part of the correct series), and after adding this to `sum`, you have

num == 7, denom == 7, sum == 1.6, and holder == 1.0.

**Conclusion**

So there are at least two errors in your logic.  The first is that after initializing `num` and `denom` to 1 and 3, respectively, you add 2 to each before calculating their ratio. What you probably *should* do instead is add 2 to each of `num` and `denom` *after* you calculate their ratio, but before jumping back to the start of the loop.

The second error, which you hopefully noticed as we stepped through the code, is that you are adding 2 to `num` *twice* with each time through the loop: once at the bottom of the loop according to your `for` specifier, and once at the top of the loop. You only need one of those increment-by-2 operations.

So an improved loop would look like:

```
        for (num=1;num<=98;num=num+2) {
                holder1 = num/denom;
                sum= sum+holder1;
                denom = denom+2;
                }
```